# Randomize a subset of Items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, random

I want to create a quiz, I have 20 items in an ArrayList that is in MainActivity. How do i pick 6 random items from the ArrayList each time i click to Open DetailActivity, passing the random items?

P.S I know how to navigate between activities and passing data through Intents, I just want to know how get 6 random items from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shuffle the `ArrayList` using `Collections.shuffle`:

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(myArray, new Random(seed));
```

In order to get 6 items, you can use `myArray.subList(0, 6)`.

Comment: Or `myArray.subList(0, 6)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Random` object :

```
Random random = new Random();
myList.get(random.nextInt(myList.size())));
```

Or you can also `Collections.shuffle(myList);` that under the hood also uses a `Random` but that should have a slight overhead as it iterates on all elements of the list.

In your case, as you need to retrieve probably 6 distinct elements, you should rather use `Collections.shuffle(myList);` as it will allow to retrieve 6 distinct elements with `myList.subList(0,6);`.
By iterating 6 times with  `myList.get(random.nextInt(myList.size())));`, you could have multiple times the same element.

Comment: This method can have repeats, it does not pick 6 unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer>  list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(1);
lista.add(2);
lista.add(1);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(4);
lista.add(5);
lista.add(6);
.
.
.

Collections.shuffle(list);
```

now you can get index 0 to 5 and its randomized

Answer (score 0):

To generate number between `0` and `list.size()` use:

```
int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(list.size());
```

Having random index you can get element from list:

```
list.get(index);
```